# LinkedIn only posting text before url

Tags: linkedin-api

When I post this with the linkedin share api:

> Join our exclusive newsletter (dogfluence.beehiiv.com) about
> constructing effective content in the dog industry. Grab this valuable
> chance to expand your dog brand. #petnews #dognews #newsletter
> #beehiiv #dogfluence

Only this is posted:

> Join our exclusive newsletter

So it stops before the link? Why is that the case?

My code:

This is the content in my post request (and bearer token of course):

```
array:6 [
  "author" => "urn:li:organization:94206834"
  "commentary" => "Join our exclusive newsletter (https://dogfluence.beehiiv.com) about constructing effective content in the dog industry. Grab this valuable chance to expand your dog brand. #petnews #dognews #newsletter #beehiiv #dogfluence"
  "visibility" => "PUBLIC"
  "distribution" => array:3 [
    "feedDistribution" => "MAIN_FEED"
    "targetEntities" => []
    "thirdPartyDistributionChannels" => []
  ]
  "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED"
  "isReshareDisabledByAuthor" => false
]
```

Full code:

```
$res = Http::withHeaders([
"LinkedIn-Version" => "202301",
"X-Restli-Protocol-Version" => "2.0.0",
"Content-Type" => "application/json"
])
->withToken($post->account->bearer_token)
->post(
    env("LINKEDIN_API") . "posts",
    array_merge(
        [
            "author" => $post->account->account_id,
            "commentary" => $post->description,
            "visibility" => "PUBLIC",
            "distribution" => [
                "feedDistribution" => "MAIN_FEED",
                "targetEntities" => [],
                "thirdPartyDistributionChannels" => [],
            ],
            "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
            "isReshareDisabledByAuthor" => false,
        ],
        $this->mapArticle($post),
        $this->mapMedia($media)
    )
);
```

Seriously what is going on here?